Data structure for querying sets by a partial list of elements
Let's say I have a set of sets, for example:
{
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
  {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
  {5, 6, 7, 8},
  {4, 7, 9},
}

I'd like to make some queries such as:
"which sets contain {3, 5, 7}?"
This is probably a very similar problem that Search Engines need to solve when searching for multiple keywords. I suppose the obvious solution is to use a reverse index and have every element pointing to a list of references to sets that contain itself; and then somehow intersect those lists.
Is there something more efficient/clever?
Would the answer be different if all sets contained the same number of elements or they were reasonably bounded (e.g. 16 bits numbers) to something that could fit in a bit-array?

It's the old time/space tradeoff. You either spend the time searching through all the sets with every query, or you create an inverted index that occupies space proportional to the total number of items in the sets.
